# Fine Uploader S3 - Return Uploaded URL on Complete callback

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

How can i get the full image url of the uploaded image on my amazon s3 bucket with fine-uploader?

My javascript code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#fine-uploader").fineUploaderS3({
        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: 'bucket.s3.amazonaws.com',
            accessKey: 'xxxxxxxx'
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 'end.php '
        },
        uploadSuccess: {
            endpoint: 'success.php '
        },
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: 'success.html '
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true
        },
        validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['
                jpeg ', '
                jpg ', '
                png '],
            sizeLimit: 1048576
        }
    }).on('
    complete ', function (event, id, name, response) {
        console.log(response.tempLink);
   });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Following the s3 demo i am using the `response.tempLink` and just trying to log it to the console and then i will use it later on. The upload always works fine but my console returns an undefined response everytime.

From finding this q&a: [having trouble displaying an image uploaded to Amazon s3 by fine-uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369235/having-trouble-displaying-an-image-uploaded-to-amazon-s3-by-fine-uploader#18370813)

It seems like my IAM user/policy settings and `$serverPublicKey` and `$serverPrivateKey` might be the cause? My setup is:

Exact copy of this file for my end.php file:
https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-cors.php

with the following changes:

```
// changed to match the secret access key for the FIRST IAM user as discussed in the docs
$clientPrivateKey = 'user_secret_key...';

// bucket name
$expectedBucketName = "my.bucket.name";

// changed to match the access and secret of the SECOND IAM 'server' user
$serverPublicKey = 'server_user_access_key...';
$serverPrivateKey = 'server user secret key...';

// updated to my website
function handlePreflightedRequest() {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.mywebsite.com');
}
```

In my Amazon IAM console I have mt SECOND IAM 'server' user setup as:

Group:
grp-server

Group Policy: (is GetObject the correct action?)

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
     "Action":"s3:GetObject",
     "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::my.bucket.name/*"
    }]
}
```

or i've tried the following which gives full admin access just to check

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement":[{
    "Effect":"Allow",
     "Resource":"*"
    }]
}
```

User: 
user-server
added to grp-server (which inherits group policy)

```
user-server access key becomes $serverPublicKey in end.php
user-server secret key becomes $serverPrivateKey in end.php
```

Am i missing anything from this?

Comment: This is covered in the demo at http://fineuploader.com/demos#amazon-demo.  Your server just needs to return the URL in it's JSON response.

Comment: Thanks @RayNicholus but i still cannot get this to work. My response link is always undefined. I have edited and updated my original question with further details...

Comment: If the response object doesn't contain tempLink, then your server is not returning a JSON response that contains a tempLink property.  You'll need to take a closer look at your server code.  Based on what you've pasted here, you indeed are not returning a JSON response with a responseLink property.

Comment: when i use `console.dir(response);` i get the console response shown in screenshot: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2nibp6s.jpg

Comment: `GetObject` is correct. `$clientPrivateKey` should be the client's SECRET key. Right now it looks like you're setting it to `'user_access_key...'` which leads me to believe you are using the wrong key for that.

Comment: @MarkFeltner - sorry that was a typo in my post, it is as you say the secret not access key that i am using but it still doesn't respond

Comment: If you are using them same code from fine-uploader-server, then both your endpoints need to point to the same PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Have your `uploadSuccess.endpoint` return a [pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that you then handle in the `onComplete` handler. Note that pre-signed URLs can only be generated server-side. See [this PHP server for details](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-thumbnails-cors.php#L241-L248).

Comment: Thanks Mark but i still cannot get this working. I've updated my question with further info if you have any ideas?

Comment: @odd_duck Look at the PHP server that mark referenced.  If you implement that properly, this will work as expected.

Comment: I've just tried changing my end.php to the one linked at `https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-thumbnails-cors.php#L241-L248` instead of the original `https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-cors.php` but still i get no response. The `serverPublicKey` and `serverPrivateKey` are they correct or should they be left blank? Everything is setup exactly as i have layed out above

Comment: They must point to your keys, as the comments in the file suggest.

Comment: and the keys are correctly configured as detailed in the initial question (a second user not the first set used for the uploading)? Sorry to be a pain and keep going on about this but i just cannot get any response back. Is the issue going to be in my endpoint.php file or in the CORS, policy, user setup in aws?

Comment: It looks like your server simply isn't returning a response that contains a tempLink property.  This is clear in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @RayNicholus i think the problem may be to do with the success.php page for my `endpoint` of `uploadSuccess` I couldn't see in the docs what actually goes into this file? At the moment it is just an empty php file

Comment: Please read http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/amazon-s3.html#optional-server-side-tasks-all-browsers.  Also, the PHP example already handles all of this for you (https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/s3/s3demo-thumbnails.php).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53836/discussion-between-odd-duck-and-ray-nicholus)